# Can I read code from a previously run python script

Tags: python, linux, recovery

I ran a python file using the command python file.py and it executed successfully. Right after I managed to delete the file, can I recover the code that was run in the previous command? I still have the terminal open and have not typed anything else into it. Running ubuntu.

Comment: This is nothing specific to python. If you have erased a file by mistake and have no backup, there are file recovery software out there you can try, with no guarantee...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you had imported the file instead of running it directly, a .pyc file would have been created containing the compiled bytecode which you could easily transform back into the regular python code (minus the comments.) However, you did run the script directly, so there is no .pyc file.

If you deleted the file in a GUI file browser, the file might have been sent into a "trash bin" where you might be able to recover it from.

Assuming you deleted the file using the "rm" command in the terminal, however, the data *might* still be on the disk provided it hasn't been overwritten ("deleting" files normally just marks the data to be overwritten on the disk)

If you're lucky, you might be able to recover it. The process isn't exactly simple, though, and there's no guarantee that the file hasn't already been overwritten since the disk is pretty much in constant use when you're using the system. More info on that here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

There's also a handy utility called lsof which you can use to recover a 'deleted' file if there's still an open file handle for it:

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c00833030

Also, in the future, I recommend using "rm -i" instead of just rm with no options as that will at least prompt you to confirm if you're sure you want to delete something first. You can also make an alias for this in your shell so that regular rm just points to 'rm -i'